# LayoutInflater for using xml and View class

Tags: android, xml, layout, view

after I asked if I should use XML or a View class for my project you told me, that I should do everything possible in XML and use a class for the rest. You told me, that animating Sprites isn't possible with XML so I wanted to make a View Class. I got the tip to google "LayoutInflater" for this and I did.

There aren't many Informations about inflaters so I visited android's developers database and tried to find out how this works.

As far as I know now, you have to put something into the onCreate method of your main game activity (the setContentView has to be the mainXML).

So now I created a LinearLayout in my mainXML and called it "container" and made this being a ViewGroup called "parent".

Now I have created a global variable "private View view" and wrote this line:

`view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(new ViewClass(this),
                null);`

Thw Problem now is that u can't inflate a class like this and I think I'm doing this whole inflating thing wrong.

Do you have any tips and tricks for me for making it work to have a LinearLayout in my mainXML and being able to make the content from my View Class appear in it?

EDIT:

Got it to work without errors, but nothing happens if I start my game now.

Here is the code pls answer if u have any solutions:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // inflate mainXML->
    View mainView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_game, null);
    // find container->
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) mainView.findViewById(R.id.container);
    // initialize your custom view->
    view = new GameLayout(this);
    // add your custom view to container->
    container.addView(view);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
```

And my GameLayout:

```
public GameLayout(Context context) 
{
    super(context);     
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

Comment: use activity context instead of `getBaseContext()`. What is `new ViewClass(this)`?

Comment: This is the Class, in which I want to code my input for the LinearLayout (I know it's stupid to put this there but I wanted you to know, what I'm trying to do)

Comment: does your ViewClass extend view?

Comment: Yes it does, but inflate(int, ViewGroup) doesnt accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of going about this. I'll show you one of them. Do the following in your `onCreate(Bundle)` before calling `setContentView(...)`:

```
// inflate mainXML
View mainView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mainXML, null);

// find container
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) mainView.findViewById(R.id.container);

// initialize your custom view
view = new ViewClass(this);

// add your custom view to container
container.addView(view);
```

Finally:

```
setContentView(mainView);
```

Alternatively, you can place your custom view inside mainXML:

```
<your.package.name.ViewClass
    android:id="@+id/myCustomView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    .... />
```

Comment: I have a little problem with the first solution. Is this everything I have to do? Will my onDraw method of the ViewClass be called and i can then set the background color black? (canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);)? Because if this is everything I have to do, it doesn't work like this. If I start my app the LinearLayout stays white.

Comment: @ChrisDürr Could you post your updated code above? I'd like to take a look at it.

Comment: Did it I thought I have done everything like you said or did I misunderstand you? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ChrisDürr You have `setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);` in your code. It should be `setContentView(mainView);` because that's the view that we inflated before and added your custom view to.

Comment: Awww man didn't see that because I was so busy with changing the mainXML stuff to activity_game etc. Thank you for helping me out with that now everything is running smoothly! Think I understood now how it's working great help ty!